# How to suppress wrong intellisense from non-current configuration in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cross-compiling, intellisense

I'm developing a cross-platform(Win11 and Android) project using Visual Studio and CMake. I created multiple CMake configuration to build library of the two platform separately:
[image: My configurations]

But I've found a weird situation that through currently I selected `x64-Debug` configuration, Visual Studio still show a lot of Intellisense error from `android-Release` :
[image: False errors]

Actually these error are all FALSE because when I build the `android-Release` version it   just works well.
[image: normally build procession]

How to suppress those false errors? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, where I got intellisense warnings for a non-current cmake configuration because that configuration had an out-of-date prebuild target artifact. There's an option you can toggle to disable this:

Go to Tools > options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced, then scroll down until you find the option "Disable IntelliSense for Inactive Platforms". Set that to true and you should be good to go.

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/intellisense-enhancements-for-cpp-open-folder-and-cmake/

Comment: That's the pretty solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same project/environment as you, so it is difficult to reproduce the same issue.

But since your problem is intellisense issue and "the errors are all false because the build will be no problem."

I suggest you close the Visual Studio instance, go to the solution root folder and remove the .vs folder:

[image]

After that, reopen the visual studio, after generating and loading, the issue may disappear. I suggest this because sometimes the project has no problem, but the content related to intellisense in the .vs folder broken and cause the issue. After remove it and reopen VS, the .vs folder will be regenerated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it just doesn't work~